# Regex fails in extracting date from larger string

Tags: java, regex, date, parsing

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2} years \\d months|\\d{1,2} years|"
                + "\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2,4}\\s+to\\s+\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2,4}").matcher(resume);

while (m.find()){
    experience = m.group();
}
```

it works fine for smaller strings but here i need to identify dates mentioned in resume.i stored resume in the string resume.

Comment: Can you add example inputs?

Comment: String word = "e important thing to remember ; about this Java matches . method is that your regular expression must 'match the 28-3-2014 to 28-3-2017 entire line. Specifically, a regex ) pattern like the following one w;ill not work with the matches method when you work on a larger line of input text";














It extracts date from above string but its not working for resume which consists of the date in same format.



if dates like 2 years or 2 years 2 months it works fine

Comment: how big is the resume string when the regex doesn't match ?

Comment: I didn't get you. The resume is two sheets long and i stored it in the String resume and tried to match it.

Comment: is there any other method to identify dates in a larger string other than regex? @freedev

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match these dates with any formatting applied, you need to account for more whitespace and any other text in your regex:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
  "^.*?" + // Start of line, then anything, non-greedy.
  "(?:" + // Non-capturing group
  "\\d{1,2}\\s*years(?:[,\\s]*\\d{1,2}\\s*months)?|" + // Years with optional months
  "\\d{1,2}\\s*[\\-/]{1}\\d{1,2}\\s*[\\-/]{1}\\d{2,4}\\s*to\\s*" + // From to To, 1/2
  "\\d{1,2}\\s*[\\-/]{1}\\d{1,2}\\s*[\\-/]{1}\\d{2,4}" + // From to To 2/2
  ")" + // Non-capturing group closes
  ".*$" // Anything else up to the end of the line
).matcher("");
```

If you need your regex to match lines, you have to feed the `Matcher` with lines:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(resume));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  if (matcher.reset(line).matches()) {
    experience = matcher.group();
  }
}
```

Example matches:

```
" 5 years"
"12 years, 10 months."
"  10/12/2010 to 3/2/12: Blah"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried ur method but its returning null.If i try it in a separate java class its executing but not in my class.why? @vagelis

Comment: I think it's pretty plain: 1) Make sure `resume` is text containing **newlines**. 2) Prepare the `Matcher` with something like `Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<REGEX>").matcher("")` (my answer is wrong there, I'll be correcting it). 3) Feed the resume line-by-line using the `BufferedReader` - `StringReader` combination.

Comment: can i do it using nlp? If so how?

Comment: @priya what exactly do you mean by "nlp"??